# Mairsil, the Pretender Out of Battlefield abilities

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Mairsil, the Pretender](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMairsil%2c%20the%20Pretender%5d) ability work on activated abilities that are not reliant on being on the battlefield?
Or is his second ability only in effect while he-himself is on the field?

For instance [Yuriko, the Tiger's Shadow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bYuriko%2c%5d%2b%5bthe%5d%2b%5bTiger%27s%5d%2b%5bShadow%5d) activated keyword *Commander ninjutsu*? Or [Reassembling Skeleton](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReassembling%20Skeleton%5d)?
(If either is a bad example please use a better example of an activated ability usable from another zone, hand, graveyard, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified, static abilities like the second ability of Mairsil, the Pretender function only while the card is on the battlefield.

> 604.2. Static abilities create continuous effects, some of which are prevention effects or replacement
>   effects. **These effects are active as long as the permanent with the ability remains on the battlefield
>   and has the ability**, or as long as the object with the ability remains in the appropriate zone, as
>   described in rule 112.6.
>
> 112.6. Abilities of an instant or sorcery spell usually function only while that object is on the stack.
>   **Abilities of all other objects usually function only while that object is on the battlefield.** The exceptions are as follows: [...]

To clear up some confusion: All abilities that aren't spell abilities, activated abilities or triggered abilities are static abilities and are subject to the rules I mentioned above. But there are some exceptions to rule 112.6 that define which abilities might be effective even outside the battlefield. Some examples are:

- Characteristic-defining abilities (like "This card is all colors.")
- Abilities that say that say that they function in a specific zone.
- Abilities that modify the deck-building rules (like "A deck can have any number of cards named Relentless Rats.")